# Proving that a Volterra operator is bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that the operator $Tf(x)=\int_a^b k(x,y)f(y)dy$, with $f\in L_2[a,b]$ and $\int _a^b \int _a^b |k(x,y)|^2dxdy<\infty$, is in $B(L_2[a,b])$. I know how to prove the linearity. For the boundedness, I have done the following:
$$ \| Tf\| = \langle Tf, Tf \rangle^{1/2} $$
$$ =(\int Tf(x)^2dx)^{1/2} $$ 
$$ =\big(\int (\int  k(x,y)f(y)dy)^2 dx\big)^{1/2}$$
(I have seen this following inequality on StackExchange but I don't know the reason!)
$$ \leq \big(\int (b-a)\int  |k(x,y)|^2|f(y)|^2 dy dx \big)^{1/2}$$
How can I further simplify this? Also, why is that $T$ maps a function to a function in $L_2[a,b]$?

PS. $B(L_2[a,b])$ is the set of bounded linear operators from $ L_2[a,b] $ to $ L_2[a,b] $.

Comment: Something is wrong in your definition of $T$. It should be $Tf(x) = \int_a^x k(x,y)f(y)\ \mathsf dy$. As written the result is a real number, not a function.

Comment: The output of T is a function. But I don’t know why it’s in [a,b].

Comment: If the bounds of the integral are $a$ and $b$ then the output of $T$ will be a real number. You need the bounds of the integral to depend on $x$.

Comment: I just checked the question again. It says the integration range is between a and b.

Comment: Perhaps the question was written incorrectly then. Take for instance $k(x,y)=1$ and $f(x) = x$. Then
$$
Tf(x) = \int_a^b y\ \mathsf dy = \frac12(b^2 - a^2),
$$
which clearly is not a function of $x$.

Comment: What is your condition of $k$? The integral related to $k$ seems not well-posed.

Comment: No conditions on $k$! Just that its 2-p integrable.

Comment: I just modified the condition on k a bit in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}|f(y)||k(x,y)|dy\leq\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(x,y)|^{2}dy\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(y)|^{2}dy\right)^{1/2},
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\|Tf\|_{L^{2}}^{2}&\leq\int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(y)||k(x,y)|dy\right)^{2}dx\\
&\leq\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2}\int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(x,y)|^{2}dy\right)dx\\
&=:K\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2},
\end{align*}
where $K=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}|k(x,y)|^{2}dydx$.

Comment: What is the first inequity you’ve used?

Comment: Holder's inequality.

Comment: Can you please write the inequality in its general form? I’m not from a math background.

Comment: $\|fg\|_{L^{1}}\leq\|f\|_{L^{2}}\|g\|_{L^{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks. Also do you know why the image of $T$ is in $L_2[a,b]$?

Comment: Just because $\|Tf\|_{L^{2}}\leq\sqrt{K}\|f\|_{L^{2}}<\infty$.